# Apple pay supression - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, applepay, core-nfc

I have an app where I want to scan an Aztec code into a reader (that also reads NFC). The problem is that this triggers apple pay, and apple pay blocks the screen so that the Aztec cant be read. I need to suppress apple pay to use my app.

This is done by applying to apple and get an entitlement which I have applied to my provisioning profile. Now all I have to do is to add the following code:

```
PKPassLibrary.RequestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppression((PKAutomaticPassPresentationSuppressionResult r) => { });
```

And add the entitlement to the Entitlement.plist.

This works for a "clean" app with nothing in it, but does not work for my app.

Any suggestions as to what can be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Entitlement.plist was not included in the project. This was done by adding the path to it under  "Custom Entitlements"

Comment: 1. In what file did you add `PKPassLibrary.RequestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppression`?
2. What exactly did you add in Entitlement.plist?
3. What if there is no such file in my project, the `Entitlement.plist` does not exist?
4. How include it to the project?

Comment: 1. Anywhere I think. I added it to my ViewWillAppear on one of my ViewControllers. 2. You need to add the special NFC entitlement (google it). 3. Hmm I dont know maybe you can make one? Copy from a new project? 4. What I did was open my soulution, right-click it and select properties. From there in the menu select IOS Bundle Signing and then Custom Entitlements -> set path to your entitlements file